# Why are my firebase storage security rules are not enforcing and letting users upload images over the limit?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have setup my storage security rules to only allow authenticated users to post images that are less than **3mb** with the following rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
          // Only allow uploads of any image file that's less than 3MB
      allow write: if request.resource.size < 3 * 1024 * 1024
                   && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*');
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

However, I just tested from my client and I was able to upload a picture that is **14mb**. I have given plenty of time for security rules to set.

How did I bypass this rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the other answers provided you with security rules you could use, it’s also good to add that you can test your security rules using the Firebase [rules playground](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator#use_the). Using this tool, you can tell exactly the resolution of each of your rules when tested against an event (create, read, update, delete).

I tested your security rules and received this output:

[image]

As you can see, while your file size limit rule is working fine, the broader `allow write: if request.auth != null;` rule is still letting your request go through. This is what the other answers pointed out and what is included in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language#building_conditions):

> If any of the “allow” rules for the method are satisfied, the request is allowed. Additionally, if a broader rule grants access, rules grant access and ignore any more granular rules that might limit access.

Comment: @LukasVis were you able to resolve the problems with your security rules?

Answer (score 2):

Please see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/core-syntax#overlapping_match_statements):

> In the case where multiple allow expressions match a request, the access is allowed if any of the conditions is true

So in your case:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

let the user to write files with any size.

I think this is the rule you want:

```
allow write: if request.auth != null &&
                request.resource.size < 3 * 1024 * 1024 && 
                request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*');
allow read: if request.auth != null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;` which overrides the previous one. Try removing write from 2nd line:

```
match /{allPaths=**} {
  // Only allow uploads of any image file that's less than 3MB
  allow write: if request.resource.size < 3 * 1024 * 1024
                   && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*');
  allow read: if request.auth != null;
}
```